Program freezes when trying to add a doc to firestore DB with Flask server with Cloud Run
I have the following code which I'm trying to run on my Cloud Run server:
cred = credentials.Certificate("firebaseCertificate.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/something', methods=["POST"])
def some_route():
    some_id = req["some_id"]
    print(some_id)
    # Nothing prints after here, nothing happens in the Firestore DB
    
    db = firestore.client()
    doc_ref = db.collection('some_collection').document(some_id)
    doc_data = doc_ref.get().to_dict()
    if doc_data == None:
        doc_data = {}
    doc_data['my_condition'] = True 
    doc_ref.set(doc_data)
    print("done modifying changes to firestore")
    return "Done!"

After the first print (which is normally displayed), nothing display unto the terminal, no errors, nothing. After a look at my Firestore DB, no document has been added or been modified.
This happens on my Cloud Run container and also on my local machine. Am I doing something wrong with making a doc on Firestore with firebase_admin.
You might also be thinking that I should be using Cloud Functions, which, for this bit of code, I should, but for the global code to work, I can't due to external dependencies that you need to use a custom docker container to install.
Edit: It now just gives me a timeout error. The errors occur whilst trying to get data from the db or setting it with doc_ref.set. I have a perfectly valid (I tested resetting it) firebaseCertificate.json so I don't get what's going wrong.
This sort of code was used in another endpoint and worked perfectly well.
Edit 2: I managed to get it to work on my machines. I don't know exactly what changed it, but deleting old containers on Artifact registry seemed to help on Cloud Run and, for my local Windows machine, I just had to sync the time again (it was 2 hours early).

you're not returning anything at the end of the function, a Flask app needs a return value for the routes to use to create the response to the HTTP request.
A simple string would suffice. Read up here for more details.
@app.route('/something', methods=["POST"])
def some_route():
    some_id = req["some_id"]
    print(some_id)
    # Nothing prints after here, nothing happens in the Firestore DB
    
    db = firestore.client()
    doc_ref = db.collection('some_collection').document(some_id)
    doc_data = doc_ref.get().to_dict()
    if doc_data == None:
        doc_data = {}
    doc_data['my_condition'] = True 
    doc_ref.set(doc_data)
    return "done modifying changes to firestore"


I edited it (I forgot to put that line in the post). However, it still doesn't do anything. Firebase and Google Cloud have been acting really weirdly for the last 2 days and I don't understand what's going on. At this point, it might be on their side. For example, I'll redeploy with only having added a print statement and it'll break.

that is extremely weird, as your code is as close to the quickstart as it can be regarding FireStore. So it fails on the get sometimes and the set at other times? Because with the adjusted code that should not happen. The only thing I can think of that is similar would be if you're rate-limited somehow, but that should generate a specific rate-limitation error

It worked perfectly fine until around 2 days ago where my entire google cloud became very strange, failed builds 50% of the time, and now this. I don't know if it might be on their side because I barely changed any code, especially not any critical code for anything to work.
